# Trying to understand a code construct in evercookie

Tags: javascript, function, scope, anonymous-function

I've been trying to understand Samy Kamkar's evercookie code and he does at least one thing I simply don't understand. The relevant code can be seen online at http://code.google.com/p/beef/source/browse/trunk/modules/beefjs/lib/evercookie.js?spec=svn604&r=604.

My question is about how this code sets `evercookie` itself. The relevant construct:

```
var evercookie = (function () {
  this._class = function() { 
      ... 
  }; 
  return _class;
})();
```

I understand that `evercookie` is intended to be a constructor (despite not following the convention of capitalizing constructors) and I understand that `evercookie` is being set to the return of an anonymous, self-executing function. Unless I am more confused than I think I am, `evercookie` should be set to the value `_class` has in the scope of the outer (anonymous) function. What I **don't** follow: where does `_class` get a value? `_class` is not the same thing as `this._class`, and there is no other reference to `_class`.

Comment: I think this._class is pretty much the same as var _class. Creating a local variable named _class. Just like window.test is the same as test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that function `_class` is the same as `this._class` because `this` references the window object in the automatically executed function. It's essentially making the `_class` function a global variable.

Here's the basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/hYQab/

Comment: Ooh. OK. Weird, though. Is there any good reason at all to write it that way? Do I understand correctly that you are saying it is exactly the same as if he had consistently written either _class or this._class, and that the only additional effect of writing it this way is obscurity?

Comment: I'd wager that he doesn't fully understand what he's doing there.

Comment: Given who wrote it, I'd be more inclined to wager he just threw in something very obscure out of sheer contrariness.

Comment: I'm not saying he is an idiot, but possible just missed it because it does technically work, even if it's not best practices. I sometimes make a string of variables like `var one = 1, two = 2; three = 3;` and miss the semicolon after `two`, which makes `three` global. It's really not a good idea to make things global unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: As a disclaimer, I'm unfamiliar with his project and am basing it based on your question above, he may have a valid reason for doing it that I may not understand given the limited context. I wouldn't change it if you have faith he knows what he's doing, just be aware that you can overwrite the internals if they're made global.

Comment: This is the same guy who wrote the Samy worm. These days he claims to be 'white hat', and I'm guessing he really is, but hacker coding habits die hard.